# asio - segmentation fault when including io_service.hpp and windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, boost-asio

I meet a strange behavior with asio on windows: a segmentation fault occurs on some `io_service.post()`. Here is the code I use:

main.cpp:

```
#include <asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

#include "foo.h"

asio::io_service ios;

int main()
{
    ios.post(foo);

    ios.run();

    return 0;
}
```

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <asio/io_service.hpp>

void foo();

#endif
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

extern asio::io_service ios;

void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }

void foo()
{
    ios.post(bar);
}
```

And I compile with:
    g++ -o test.exe -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DASIO_STANDALONE -Iasio-1.10.6/include foo.cpp main.cpp -lws2_32

(note: the `ios` global object is used to simplify the code, but in my real program, the io_service object is created in `main` and accessed by reference in the `foo` callback).

When executing, I get a segmentation fault on the `post` call.

My environment: windows 7, mingw-w64 5.2 with dwarf2, asio 1.10.6.
I get the same bug using mingw-w64 4.7.2 and 4.9.3, and using boost.asio 1.55.

To fix the crash, some workarounds are available:

- always include io_service.hpp before windows.h (or vice versa)
- define ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP (or BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP when using boost.asio)
- NOT define _WIN32_WINNT

I would be sure that my code is correct before reporting a bug on the asio project. For me, this is not acceptable to impose the inclusion order of io_service.hpp and windows.h: these two headers are usually indirectly included by other headers so it is very difficult to control that.

Comment: it looks then as if the different include orders make the resulting objects violate the ODR. You might want to report this to the Asio devs